# How to get the current ul li's length in javascript , when i tried to sort them?

Tags: javascript

```
<ul id="types" style="list-type:none;">

<li id="categories" style="list-type:none;">1
<ul>
    <li style="list-type:none;">1</li><br/>
    <li style="list-type:none;">1</li>
</ul>
</li>

<li id="categories" style="list-type:none;">2
<ul>
    <li style="list-type:none;">2</li><br/>
    <li style="list-type:none;">2</li>
</ul>
</li>

<li id="categories" style="list-type:none;">3
<ul>
    <li style="list-type:none;">3</li><br/>
    <li style="list-type:none;">3</li>
</ul>
</li>

</ul>
```

i am moving the li up and down ,when i am doing like this i have written the code for calling one jquery _mouseStop function(event,noPropagation))

in this function i am writing

```
var tagetNode = this.currentItem[0].parentNode.id

if (this.element[0].id == "categories") {
    var targetlistlength = document.getElementById(targetListId).getElementsByTagName("li").length;
    // var targetlistlength = this.parentNode.getElementsByTagName("li").length;
    var PageIds = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < targetlistlength; i++) {
        PageIds += document.getElementById(targetListId).getElementsByTagName("li")[i].getAttribute("value") + ",";
    }

}
```

when i am sorting the child li's the above function get called but it is always getting the first child ul of first li length only.. i want the current ul li's length which i am trying to sort

i have tried with the commented line also to get the length of li's but iam getting error as this.parentNode is undefined

anyone  please suggest me what can i do

Comment: Your JavaScript code contains no jQuery; is that intentional, or is jQuery available to you?

Comment: If you're using jQuery, why not use $ instead of document.getElementById()?

Comment: I guess the OP intentionally added `jquery` tag to fulfill minimum requirements for 'Ask a Question'

Comment: sorry in my .js file i am also having jquery code.. i use some times javascript code also in jquery to make the task easy.. any way its not the matter of jquery or javascript.. let me know the answer in javascript if u can give

Comment: Hi Diodeus i asked to javascript guys also but they are not able to answer my question .. that's why i have added the jquery tag to get the answers from you

Answer (score 0):

As there is no working demo available, you can check what you get when you use `console.log($(this));` inside that function when mouseStop event occurs in console. If you get the expected `li` in the console then you can executing the following code to get the length of its parent's childs.

```
alert($(this).parent().children().length);
```

Comment: Hi codef0rmer, because of having duplicate id's iam getting problem so i removed the if condition then it is working, and it is also getting li's lenght properly which iam trying to move.

Comment: Great, Good for you!. BTW, have you tried my code and if it works too then you can use the simplied code as it is quite readable.

Comment: Hi,i tried with your code but i doesn't work. console.log($(this)) is getting "_firebug" something like this and for $(this).parent().children().length is getting alert as 0

Comment: may be you are putting it in the wrong place. would like to see you code (on jsfiddle.net) if you want take this further?

Comment: No thanks codef0rmer, i got the result with my code its enough thank you codef0rmer

Answer (score 0):

There mustn't be multiple elements with the same id.
Try to replace them with classes or make them unique.

The if-condition could be the following if you have unique id's (e.g. categories-1, categories-2, ...)

```
if (this.element[0].id.match("^categories") != null) { ... }
```

Or if you use classes the if-condition could be:

```
if (this.element[0].className.match("(^| )categories( |$)") != null) { ... }
```

Comment: Hi Jasd thanks for giving answer , because of having duplicate id's iam getting problem so i removed the if condition then it is working, and it is also getting li's lenght properly which iam trying to move.

Comment: Ahh i see, if-condition is not longer necessary because currentItem now holds the right item...